# Trigger not deleted in quartz 2.16

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz 2.1.6 with Weblogic 12 in clustered mode (actually only 1 dev machine) and using standard the JDBC delegate (`org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate`)

I may have multiple triggers per request. The trigger is associated to a durable job, and I'm deleting all triggers associated with a single request with the below code:

```
Scheduler sched;
    try {
        sched = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler("MyScheduler");
        Set<TriggerKey> triggerKeys =                sched.getTriggerKeys(triggerGroupEquals(String.valueOf(requestId)));
        for (TriggerKey k : triggerKeys) {
            if (sched.unscheduleJob(k)) {
                logger.info("Removed trigger " + k.toString() + " for request " + requestId);
            }
        }
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
```

In the log I see the message "Removed trigger 123 for request abc" but the trigger still is there in the database and still fires the job. I have no exception trace in the console. I'm using XA datasource but the called EJB business method is annotated as supporting transaction. I see no rollback. Sporadically the trigger is deleted but not instantly.

What am I missing?

What JDBC delegate should I declare in `quartz.properties` if I'm using Weblogic 12 with an Oracle 11 DBMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would check the following: 
- Make sure the DB connection is "Auto-Commit", unless so your operation will not be persisted.

- You may have a transaction issue, check txn log.

Comment: Actually, as said in the description, the ejb business method was stating : 

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)

It should rather state :
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)


Correct transaction declaration fixed the issue.


Thank you

Comment: Anytime :) I am glad it helped to solve your problem, I also experienced some problems with Quartz... Cheers, Uri